# String conversion error when reading user input

Tags: python

I get the following error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'asdf\n'

from this code:

```
import sys

print('Hello, this is a short quiz. Please tell me your name')
name = int(sys.stdin.readline())
print('Are you ready %s?' % (name))
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to convert the name to an int?

Comment: You're typing "asdf" and it's failing to convert it to an int... how do you expect "asdf" to be converted to an integer?

Comment: Also, you're not showing your actual code - that would produce a different error message. By the way, why not use the `input()` function instead of `sys.stdin.readline()`? Where did you see that?

Comment: Aside: question titles are designed to be useful both to people looking to help and to aid searches by other people with the same problem.  "What's wrong with my code?" is a little generic..

Comment: You could change it to `int(sys.stdin.readline(), 36)` to change any non-punctuated single-word name (like `'asdf'` or `'Prince'`… but not `'\u01ac\u030a\u0335\u032c'` aka `'Ƭ̵̬̊'`) into a number. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, but I'm not sure why you were trying that `int` in the first place…

Comment: @vanza `int('asdf', 36)`, of course ;)

Answer (score 4):

Unless your name is "7", that code is guaranteed to fail. You are casting the input string to an `int`. Try:

```
name = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

Comment: Dude, I watched as you got three different up votes in the first 30 seconds, lol.

Comment: It could also be 007. That would be cooler.